# Bitwise Selection out of Array of Strings

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have an array of string values (`"A","B","C","D"`) where a separate integer value denotes a bitwise mapping of the array.  The string values are mapped as (`8,4,2,1`) such that a resul value of 10 denotes (`"A","C"`) or a bitwise extrapolation.  I am trying to build a function around this so I can pass in the integer and get back either an array of string values or a concatenated (delimited) string result.

If this has been done, please point me to it?  I've been searching but I suspect my search terms are wrong and keeping me from finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution (thank you Ansgar Wiechers!)...

```
function Get_BitValues (intVal)
    Dim x, y, i, n, result : result = ""
    y = Array( 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 )
    x = Array( "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" )
    for i = 0 to UBound(x)
        n = 2^i
        if intVal and n Then
            if result <> "" then
                result = result & "," & x(i)
            else
                result = x(i)
            end if
        end if
    next
    Get_BitValues = result
end function

wscript.echo Get_BitValues(80)
wscript.echo Get_BitValues(127)
wscript.echo Get_BitValues(42)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using an integer value as a bitmask, so you need to use a logical `And` operation to check if the given value has a particular bit set:

```
10 And 23 ⇔ 10 And 8 ⇒ 8
10 And 22 ⇔ 10 And 4 ⇒ 0
10 And 21 ⇔ 10 And 2 ⇒ 2
10 And 20 ⇔ 10 And 1 ⇒ 0
```

A bit is set if the operation returns a non-zero result.

However, your mapping is is the inverse of the actual index order in the array:

```
Array value:   A  B  C  D
Array index:   0  1  2  3
Numeric value: 1  2  4  8  (20 21 22 23)
Your mapping:  8  4  2  1
```

Thus you need to calculate the value as `2max_index - index`, e.g. `23-2 = 21` for the array element `C`.

Comment: That's helpful, and I understand bitwise "and" concepts.  I'm looking for a vbscript example to use for a function wrapper.  If nobody has built such a thing (which would be surprising), I will make one.  I just prefer not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: SO is not a place where we write code for you. If you want help with an implementation we expect you to have made an effort yourself first. Show the code you currently have and explain what doesn't work as expected, and we'll help you improve from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary. A Dictionary has a key and a value. Both can be anything (and values don't need to be used).

```
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dict.Add "A", "1"
            For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
                msgbox thing
            Next
            'or
            msgbox Dict.Item("A")
```